# Browser ignore my JVM parameters in JNLP

Tags: java, browser, applet, jvm, jnlp

I try to test the JVM parameters with this JNLP file :

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">

    <information>
        <title>Test Applet</title>
        <vendor>D2D - Architecture - Composants</vendor>
    </information>

    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <!--<j2se version="1.7*" href="" java-vm-args="-ea -Xincgc -verbose -Xmx768m" />-->

        <j2se version="1.6*" href="" initial-heap-size="512" max-heap-size="1024M" />

        <jar href="Applet.jar" main="true" />
        <!-- Si plusieurs jars : mettre plusieurs balises jar -->
    </resources>

    <applet-desc 
         name="Test Applet"
         main-class="TestApplet"
         width="600"
         height="300">
    </applet-desc>

    <update check="always"/>

</jnlp>
```

When i launch the "jnlp", it taking in the account this but when i launch from a html page with this script :

```
<body>
        <h1>Prototype Applet JRE</h1>

        <!-- Script JavaScript pour le déploiement de l'applet -->
    <script src="javaScript/deployJava.js"></script>

    <!-- Les différentes informations sur l'applet -->
        <script> 
            var attributes = { code:'TestApplet.class', archive:'Applet.jar'} ; 
            var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'applet.jnlp'} ; 
            deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
        </script>
</body>
```

The browser ignores this JVM parameters and launch the applet normally...but the jvm has "512" at the min...

I search a lot, test a lot, without results...

Test environment :

Browsers : Chrome 26.0.1410.43 m , IE 8.0.6..

JRE : 1.6.0_u22 / 1.7

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the location and content of `applet.jnlp`?

Comment: i update my first post for the content, the location of applet.jnlp is  in the same folder as index.html...

Comment: `initial-heap-size="512"`   512 bytes is too small.  add a moderator like `initial-heap-size="512M"`.

Comment: But if i launch the applet with "512", normally the browser reject this because too small, and that is not my case...

Comment: That last comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: ok lol,
i lauch the applet with "512" not "512M", normally the browser shows an error like "Can not create the jvm..." ?